# Relationships between altitudes and medians of a triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

[image]Median $CM$ and altitude $CH$ of $\triangle ABC$ trisect $\angle ACB.$ Find $\angle ACB$

Ok so I drew the picture and I don't see how I can find the answer with no information given about the measurements.

Comment: Can you post the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let ABC be a triangle satisfying the condition for the question and let $\alpha$ be $\angle ABC$, Since $\triangle CHB$ is a right triangle we have $\angle HCB=90-\alpha$. Since we want the median and height to be trisectors all the angles at the top are $90^\circ-\alpha$.

Notice $\triangle CMB$ is an isosceles triangle since the height of that triangle is also the bisector. So if $HB$ measures $d$ then $MH$ measures $d$ also. So $AM$ must measure $2d$ since $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$.

$\triangle CAH$ is a right triangle and $CM$ is the bisector of $\angle ACM$. We want $\frac{MH}{AM}=\frac{1}{2}$. By the [bisector theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) we have $\frac{MH}{AM}=\frac{CH}{CA}$. So we want $\frac{CH}{CA}=\cos(\angle ACH)=\frac{1}{2}$.

This means $\angle ACH=60^\circ\implies \angle ACB=90^\circ$

From here we also know $180-2\alpha=60^\circ\implies \alpha=60^\circ$

To sum things up we get $\angle ACB=90^\circ, \angle CBA=60^\circ, \angle BCA=30^\circ $